# MySQL on Ubuntu /var/lib/mysql/table - What is it?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, plesk

There's a file in /var/lib/mysql simply called "table". It's 50 gig in size yet the total size of all my databases is no more than a couple of hundred megabytes. Any idea what it is, and how can i reduce it's size?

Answer (score 0):

After interrogating the file, it just looked like some maintenance logs so i truncated the file